# How to get a new line at the end of pipe command

Tags: command-line, bash, ls

I want to write a piped sequence of commands which prints out a list of all the subdirectories of the given directory, and printed in one line, following a new line.

I'm having trouble to make the output of the following command to be all at the same line, and then have a new line at the end.

This is my pipe command:

```
ls -l /share/ |grep ^d |tr -s ' ' |cut -f9 -d' '| tr '\n' ' '
```

And I would like the output to be as:

```
file1 file3
[user@linux]$
```

And not (what I actually get:

```
file1 file3[user@linux]$
```

Comment: What is `$/share/`?

Comment: I want to write a piped sequence of commands which prints out a list of all the subdirectories of the given directory, and printed in one line, following a new line.

Answer (score 9):

What about:

```
ls -l $/share/ |grep ^d |tr -s ' ' |cut -f9 -d' '| tr '\n' ' ' && echo " "
```

Comment: It's not necessary to pass any arguments to `echo`. It will print an empty new line without arguments.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you want to get only directory names, if so you can use `find`:

```
find /share -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n'
```

**Example:**

```
% find /usr -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n'
usr
include
lib
share
sbin
local
bin
games
lib32
src
```

---

**Original answer:**

Use an intelligent shell like `zsh` or use `printf`:

```
printf '%s\n' "$(ls -l /share/ |grep ^d |tr -s ' ' |cut -f9 -d' '| tr '\n' ' ')"
```

Take a look at `help printf`.

Comment: I can't use printf. (These were the instructions)

Comment: @user2953423 check my edits

Comment: `-printf '%f\n'` is great. But I thought OP needs all in one line? =)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would just be to add a plain `echo` command without any arguments to the end of the command:

```
ls -l $/share/ |grep ^d |tr -s ' ' |cut -f9 -d' '| tr '\n' ' ' ; echo
```

If you don't like the commands to be linked with `;`, you could also use:

```
echo $(ls -l $/share/ |grep ^d |tr -s ' ' |cut -f9 -d' '| tr '\n' ' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Why `ls`, `grep`, `cut`, ...?

Use `awk` and `find`:

```
find /usr/share -maxdepth 1 -type d | awk -F/ '{printf "%s ",$NF} END {print ""}'
```

Comment: Thanks, but these were the instructions.. :)

Comment: The instructions? We make your homework?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to write a piped sequence of commands which prints out a list of all the subdirectories of the given directory, and printed in one line, following a new line.

<del>You don't need a piped sequence of command for that; you can use Bash's filename expansion</del> Incidentally you'll need a piped sequence of commands for that, since apparently you don't want to print the trailing "/":

```
echo */ | tr -d '/'
```

- `echo */`: prints `*/`, which is a globbing pattern which is expanded to any folder / file in the current working directory ending with `/` (thus only to folders);
- `tr -d '/'`: deletes the trailing "/". There's no concern that "/" could appear in the file name since "/" is not a valid character for a filename.

```
% mkdir dir{1..3}
% touch file{1..3}
% tree
.
├── dir1
├── dir2
├── dir3
├── file1
├── file2
└── file3

3 directories, 3 files
% echo */ | tr -d '/'
dir1 dir2 dir3
%
```

Comment: +1 for the simplest command. Great idea, did not know that myself. ;-)